# Увеличение(масштабирование) Anchorpane вместе с основным окном

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Всем привет! Возникла проблемка. Не знаю как привязать чужой Anchorpane из другой View к границам основного View, чтобы когда развернуть окно он растягивался вместе с ним. Делаю все через SceneBuilder.
Это после того, как я как раз развернул на максимум свое окно
[image: вот мой GUI]
Серая область это как раз тот Anchorpane, к которому я пытаюсь привязать другой.
В коде основного контроллера для GettingStart.fxml я пишу

```
@FXML
    public void initialize() {

        try {

            AnchorPane marketPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/StocksView.fxml"));

            for (Node node:sidePane.getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
                System.out.println(node.getAccessibleText());
            }

            for (Node node : sidePane.getChildren()) {
                if (node.getAccessibleText() != null) {
                    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (MouseEvent ev) -> {
                        switch (node.getAccessibleText()) {
                            case "storesMenu":
                                setNode(marketPane);
                                txtCurrentWindow.setText("Stores");
                                break;
```

где StocksView.fxml имеет размеры серой области при нормальном виде.

GettingStart.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXToolbar?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialdesignicons.MaterialDesignIconView?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.octicons.OctIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.lexkom.controll.StartwindowController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="sidePane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="210.0" style="-fx-background-color: #363d49;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="102.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="136.0" text="Navigation" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Pane prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="210.0" style="-fx-background-color: #363d49;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="21.0" layoutY="18.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="165.0" text="MyDimplomaProject" textFill="WHITE">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="store" accessibleText="storesMenu" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="17.0" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="152.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="180.0" ripplerFill="WHITE" text="Stores" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <OctIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="DATABASE" size="17" />
               </graphic>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="currency" accessibleText="currancyMenu" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="17.0" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="200.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="180.0" ripplerFill="WHITE" text="Currancy Rates" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <MaterialDesignIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="CHART_AREASPLINE" size="17" />
               </graphic>
            </JFXButton>
            <Separator layoutX="15.0" layoutY="345.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="345.0" />
            <Pane layoutX="15.0" layoutY="365.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="51.0" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="1.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../resources/User_Avatar-64.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
                  <Label layoutX="53.0" layoutY="6.0" text="User name" textFill="WHITE">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="logoutBtn" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="17.0" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="435.0" onAction="#logOut" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="180.0" ripplerFill="WHITE" text="Log Out" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="SIGN_OUT" size="17" />
               </graphic>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="17.0" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="485.0" onAction="#closelabel" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="180.0" ripplerFill="WHITE" text="Exit" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="POWER_OFF" size="17" />
               </graphic>
            </JFXButton>
            <Label graphicTextGap="16.0" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="560.0" text="About" textFill="WHITE" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <JFXToolbar fx:id="window" layoutX="210.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="791.0" style="-fx-background-color: #363d49;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="209.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <center>
            <Label fx:id="txtCurrentWindow" textFill="WHITE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </center>
         <right>
            <HBox prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="129.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="60.0">
                     <children>
                        <MaterialDesignIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="WINDOW_MINIMIZE" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="34.0" onMousePressed="#minimizeStage" size="16" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
                  <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="60.0">
                     <children>
                        <MaterialDesignIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="WINDOW_MAXIMIZE" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="31.0" onMousePressed="#maximizeStage" size="16" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
                  <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="60.0">
                     <children>
                        <MaterialDesignIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="WINDOW_CLOSE" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="31.0" onMouseClicked="#closelabel" onMousePressed="#closelabel" size="16" text="" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </right>
      </JFXToolbar>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="holderPane" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="54.0" opacity="0.8" prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="780.0" style="-fx-background-color: #9a9b9d;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="215.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="4.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="54.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

StocksView.fxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="780.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <JFXTabPane layoutX="323.0" layoutY="191.0" prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="780.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <tabs>
            <Tab closable="false" text="Manage Sheets">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
              </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab closable="false" text="Store">
               <content>
                  <fx:include source="TabStockView.fxml" />
               </content></Tab>
         </tabs>
         <effect>
            <DropShadow />
         </effect>
      </JFXTabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

*StocksView.fxml*

```
<AnchorPane <!-- ... --> AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
```

или

```
case "storesMenu":
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor( marketPane, 0.0 );
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor( marketPane, 0.0 );
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor( marketPane, 0.0 );
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor( marketPane, 0.0 );
    setNode(marketPane);
```